# How to git pull while keeping uncommitted changes

Tags: git, github

How can I safely pull from remote repo to update my teammate's latest work when I am not ready to commit my latest changes yet?

I currently stash my local changes and pull, but it would often run into merging conflict. Is there a method to avoid merging conflicts as much as possible?

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Comment: You are doing it the way it has to be done and if there are conflicts it's because code involved in going in separate directions and git can not automatically merge it so no worries in that sense.

Comment: Agreed with @eftshift0 ^^ Conflicts are not errors. If they happen too often, the workflow is to be questioned.

Answer (score 1):

Stashes are sort of the work of the devil. Real commit is better than stash. Instead say

```
git switch -c temp
git add .
git commit -mwip 
git switch -
git pull
git merge temp
```

This will not fix the merge conflicts. But it will enact them in a better milieu.

However, if you have two people working on the same branch simultaneously, that is a Bad Smell and you need to stop it immediately.